# Manipulate orders json data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have order's JSON data which look like following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 640197558336,
        "line_items": [
            {
                "id": 1501742661696,
                "variant_id": 19490901426240,
                "title": "\"Acrylic Bag\"",
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 1501742661695,
                "variant_id": 19490901426245,
                "title": "\"Trash Can\"",
                "quantity": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 640197558337,
        "line_items": [
            {
                "id": 1501742661699,
                "variant_id": 19490901426249,
                "title": "\"Sports headphones\"",
                "quantity": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 1501742661695,
                "variant_id": 19490901426245,
                "title": "\"Trash Can\"",
                "quantity": 6
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have used `pandas`  to read json and view it as data-frame, please see below:

```
import pandas as pd

desired_width = 920
file_name = "trimmedorders"
file_ext = ".json"
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)

df = pd.read_json(file_name+file_ext,orient='columns')
df.head()
```

the data-frame looks like as follow:

[image]

can someone please help me in getting it into following format:

[image]

any help/suggestion in this regard is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to pre-process the JSON.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"id": i["id"], "line_items_id": j["id"], "line_items_variant_id": j["variant_id"], 
         "line_items_title": j["title"], "line_items_quantity": j["quantity"]}  for i in data for j in i["line_items"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             id  line_items_id  line_items_quantity     line_items_title  \
0  640197558336  1501742661696                    1        "Acrylic Bag"   
1  640197558336  1501742661695                    2          "Trash Can"   
2  640197558337  1501742661699                    5  "Sports headphones"   
3  640197558337  1501742661695                    6          "Trash Can"   

   line_items_variant_id  
0         19490901426240  
1         19490901426245  
2         19490901426249  
3         19490901426245
```

Comment: thanks for your time. I must be doing some silly mistake here, getting an error `string indices must be integers`

Comment: it turn out that i had to read `json` as a `dict` and then pre-process it as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) and `meta` + `record_path` keywords:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.concat([
    json_normalize(row, record_path=["line_items"], record_prefix="line_item_", meta="id")
        for row in data
])

>> print(df)

    line_item_id  line_item_quantity      line_item_title  \
0  1501742661696                   1        "Acrylic Bag"   
1  1501742661695                   2          "Trash Can"   
0  1501742661699                   5  "Sports headphones"   
1  1501742661695                   6          "Trash Can"   

   line_item_variant_id            id  
0        19490901426240  640197558336  
1        19490901426245  640197558336  
0        19490901426249  640197558337  
1        19490901426245  640197558337
```

Note that this is more expensive than @Rakesh's solution since `json_normalize` returns a `DataFrame` each time.